Induction proof for product of $a^x$ is less than or equal to the sum of $x\times a$
So this type of problem has me stuck in proving some relation. I assumed to use induction but I am stuck at a certain step and cannot understand if there is a trick or perhaps my idea is just wrong:
Let $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$ be non-negative and let $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$ be so that $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n = 1$. Show that $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{x_i} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ia_i$$
So what I did so far was try to use a logarithm like so:
$$ \log_a(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{x_i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\log_a(a_i) \leq \log_a(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ia_i) $$ First of all I don't even know if this is the correct step to make. So far, for n = 1 it is fine. However, when I add $x_{n+1}\log_a(a_{n+1})$ to both sides, and get $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i\log_a(a_i) \leq \log_a(a_{n+1}^{x_{n+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_ia_i)$$ From here I am not sure what is the next step. I am not sure how to simplify and finalize or if it is even correct. Any help appreciated.

Not sure if it is true, unless all $x_i\geq 0.$

I am sorry. It is my fault that I did not make it clear that yes, $x_i$ are all non-negative real numbers. So then, how accurate or what to change to get the proper result?

If it’s true, then I would use mathematical induction, which increases the value of $n$. Just with the same stream, see the proof of Jensen Inequality.

Oh wait. I’ve forgot sth important. This can be easily solved with Weighted AM-GM Inequality, which can be proved with the Jensen Inequality of $\ln$.
